# Django REST and request.data MultiValueDictKeyError

Tags: django, rest, dictionary

My question is connected to mechanism in Django REST Framework where we can get request data via calling request.data dictionary. The problem is when we are going to read a key which is NOT in the dictionary. Of course, we can try to check if request.data contains wanted key, as follows:

```
if not 'time_begin' in request.data:
    raise APIException()
```

As you can see, if there is no data at wanted key, Django REST Framework will show following information via response API:

```
{
    "detail": "A server error occurred."
}
```

Otherwise, if I don't use if-instruction for checking existance of the key in the dictionary, I have following error which is expected:

```
MultiValueDictKeyError at /address/
"'time_begin'"
```

My question is: can I not use the code for checking existance of key? It is smelly do not use it? If I turn off Django debugging and there no wanted key in dictionary, server responses HTTP 500 - so it's OK in some ways. On the other hand, if I must check many fields in dictionary, my code becoms very repetitive. What do you think?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

500s aren't a good meaningful response.  You should be validating just about everything.  To keep it DRY you can create helper functions to solve the general problem.  Something like:

```
def validate_request(req, keys):
    for key in keys:
        if key not in request.data:
            raise APIException('request.data missing key "{}"'.format(key))
```

Edit:  You'll have to handle the exception and return a validation error to wherever the request comes from.  If you are trying to be RESTful, then you can use [status codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) with whatever message, or a JSON response with the validation error, or the like.  Depends on your use case.